# How to upgrade the firmware of HP SAS expander card without Smart Array controller or Proliant Server?

Tags: storage, hp, sas, hp-smart-array, firmware

How can I update/upgrade/flash the firmware of an HP SAS expander card [468406-B21 [a.k.a.](http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?SearchText=468406-B21) [487738-001]](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c01733557-4%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1412070310829.876444892.199480143)?

I used to do this using Windows and a HP P410 Smart Array controller, however that controller is no longer available.

The online ROM flash component is not an option because I don't own HP Smart Array controller. Neither is the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018#!tab=features) + USB key/stick an option because that requires a ProLiant server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upgrading the HP SAS expander is possible using Linux and a SAS **HBA**.
<sub>Note: Flashing firmware to a SAS expander will likely not work when the expander is connected to a SAS **RAID** controller because that controller might hide all devices behind it from the OS. An example of a SAS HBA is [Supermicro SAS2LP-MV8](http://www.supermicro.com/products/accessories/addon/AOC-SAS2LP-MV8.cfm).</sub>

In case you haven't got Linux, you can use a Linux Live CD. You could try the [most recent Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/). A **32-bit** download will do. 64-Bit will also work.

#### 1. Prerequisites

1. Start a Linux terminal
   <sub>That is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> using the Ubuntu LiveCD.</sub>
2. Make sure your internet connection is working
   <sub>To download and install additional components</sub>
3. Make sure your SAS expander card is detected in Linux
   <sub>`# lsscsi -g | grep HP`

   Should return something like:

   `[6:0:0:0]    enclosu HP       HP SAS EXP Card  2.08  -          /dev/sg1`

   `[6:0:1:0]    enclosu HP       HP SAS EXP Card  2.10  -          /dev/sg2`</sub>

#### 2. Setup utility

You use `sg_write_buffer` version ≥ 1.15 to download microcode when the expander is connected to a host bus adapter (HBA). To download and install this utility in 32-bit Ubuntu or Debian, use:

```
# curl -O http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/libsgutils2-2_1.39-0.1_i386.deb && 
curl -O http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg3-utils_1.39-0.1_i386.deb && 
dpkg -i *_1.39-0.1_i386.deb
```

<sup>The `sg_write_buffer` utility version ≥ 1.15 — distributed in [`sg3_utils`](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg3_utils.html) version ≥ 1.39 — added a `--bpw` option to download in small chunks. An expander might require a small chunk size like 4096 bytes.</sup>

#### 3. Get and unpack HP firmware image

1. Get the expander firmware image file, for example [version 2.10 (C) — dated 9 Sep 2014](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3923501&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D3%257CswItem%253DMTX_07e17cded9e8409ea4b9d7ea74%257CswEnvOID%253D54%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D4%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken):
   `# curl -O http://downloads.hpe.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw-array/p6670438/v96061/CP022989.scexe`
   <sup>Although they sound like Windows/DOS executables, `.scexe` files from HP are really Linux executable scripts that you can view in a text editor (at least the first part).</sup>
2. Running a 64-bit Linux and having issues with the next command? Then make sure you can run 32-bit executables. The commands in Ubuntu are:
   `# dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install libstdc++6:i386`
3. To extract the firmware image from this .scexe file:
   `# mkdir tmp && chmod +x CP022989.scexe && ./CP022989.scexe --unpack=tmp && mv tmp/PUF21000.bin . && rm -r tmp/`

#### 4. Flash SAS expander

When the expander to be upgraded/flashed is named `sg1` <sub>(check with `lsscsi -g | grep HP`)</sub>, use:

```
# sg_write_buffer --mode=dmc_offs_defer --bpw=4096 --in=PUF21000.bin /dev/sg1
# sg_write_buffer --mode=activate_mc /dev/sg1
```

<sup>Older devices might only support `--mode=0x7`. Mode `0x7` is also known as `dmc_offs_save`, which does download microcode with offsets, save and activate.</sup>

#### 5. Remove temporary files

```
# rm PUF21000.bin
```

You might need to unload (for instance `modprobe -r mvsas`) and load (f.e. `modprobe mvsas`) your HBA module again or `reboot` to reflect the firmware version changes in `lsscsi -g` output.

Comment: +1 for creativity, but this sounds a bit risky. I would just update the firmware before deploying the SAS expander by using an HP server or Smart Array controller. This product is end-of-life, so the [incidence of new firmware releases is low](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=7477380&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_07e17cded9e8409ea4b9d7ea74%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument).

Comment: @ewwhite I can't weight the involved risks. Though it might be that in the background the HP tools are doing the same thing. Actually this procedure was suggested by Robert Elliott from HP Server Storage (of course without any warranties). **Regarding end-of-life**, I don't see being EOL mentioned on https://h10057.www1.hp.com/ecomcat/hpcatalog/specs/provisioner/99/468406-B21.htm Having a look at the photo you can even see a new layout PCB design: the external SFF-8088 connector is now made an internal SFF-8087 connector.

Comment: It's EOL because the expander is not compatible with Gen8 or Gen9 servers.

Comment: re: This 6G HP SAS expander might be made EOL because of the release of newer (and more expensive) [12G HP SAS expander cards](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04346272.pdf?ver=1.0) [727250-B21](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product.aspx?sku=11112540&mfg_part=727250-B21&pagemode=ca) [DL380 Gen9] and 769635-B21 [ML350 Gen9]. As long as there are **PCI express x8 slots** in the (ProLiant) server, the older 6G HP SAS expander cards will operate.

Comment: I followed this guide today and thought that it did not work because "lsscsi -g" did not reflect any changes to version string for the HP Expander Card despite successful commands, modprobe reset, restart and full shutdowns. It was only after giving up that I noticed that link negotiation now worked properly for full speed. So, even if you don't see any change to version string. It *might* have worked anyway!

Comment: The updated location to the firmware mentioned is at http://downloads.hpe.com/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-linux-fw-array/p6670438/v96061/CP022989.scexe.